# How do I prevent GHCI from evaluating an infinite stream?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Sometimes when using GHCI I accidentally try to evaluate an infinite stream (e.g. `[1..]`). It keeps printing... and printing... and printing... and printing... So the problem is that the only way to stop the printing is to quit the console, losing all the stuff that I've already done in that session. Is there a way to make GHCI take only the first x items from a list by default?

Comment: you can just *break*  by pressing `CTRL-C` (as with most other programs out there ;))

Comment: btw: if you do it in inside emacs you might have to hit C twice (C-c-c) and it will probably fill up quite a bit of memory as the buffer will remember it

Comment: Cool! I never knew that worked! I almost never use the console for anything except for a interactive console like ghci or python.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35613612/1172541 for a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt the process:

```
Prelude > let x = 1
Prelude > [1..]
lots of stuff... Interrupted.
Prelude > print x
1
```

Other than this I believe you cannot really do anything about it except starting writing your expressions with `take` to be sure to have a finite output... In the end lists are only *one* of possible infinite outputs and the ghci cannot reliably know what requires shortening and what not. He simply `show`s the result and output it.

Comment: A more general solution (if you aren't just using lists) is `take x . show`.