# How can I get `ghci` to use my `show` function?

Tags: haskell, ghc, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

Let's say you want to use your own show function (for example, `let show = take 1000 . Prelude.show`). How can you allow `ghci` to use that for printing instead of the built in `show`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461928/745903

Answer (score 12):

You can define your own [interactive print](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--interactive-print%20%E2%9F%A8expr%E2%9F%A9) function e.g:

```
module BetterPrint
betterPrint a = putStrLn (take 1000 $ show a)
```

then start ghci as

```
ghci -interactive-print=BetterPrint.betterPrint
```

Comment: Protip: assign `ghci -interactive-print=BetterPrint.betterPrint` to an alias.

Comment: You can also put this in your ~/.ghci `:set -interactive-print=betterPrint`